# What does " a humorist of no small parts" mean in this sentence please?

Tags: meaning

It was in this letter that he mentions how More, himself a humorist of no small parts, had given him the original idea for his "Praise of Folly" and very likely it was the good-natured horse-play of the More establishment which had inspired him to write that delightful piece of nonsense with which his name is forever associated.

Comment: What's the source of the quote?

Comment: Tolerance by Hendrik Willem van Loon

Comment: _Parts_ is an archaic term for _abilities_ , usually in the expression [a man of parts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/man_of_parts) .